# How to read xlsb files?

Tags: r, excel, xlsb

I am trying to read a range into a data frame from a xlsb workbook. Can I do this with the `xlsx` package in R? If not, does anyone know of a way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the `excel.link`package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=excel.link). It allows you to write / read data easily like so :

```
df<-xl[a1:b2] # if the file is open
```

or

```
df<-xl.read.file('filename.xlsb',header=TRUE, top.left.cell="A1") # if the file isn't open
```

Comment: This is a Windows-only package.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading the xlsx package [guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf), I would think the package isn't compatible for xlsb formats. xlsb stores in binary format, whereas other excel formats are in XML. xls is an Excel 95 binary format, but apparently xlsb isn't compatible with Excel versions 2003 and prior.

Your best bet might be to try RODBC, or to save your workbook as a .csv and import from there.

Comment: RODBC is too slow,how could it quickly?